# Laravel 7: how to redirect to success page with Paypal after transaction?

Tags: laravel, paypal

I'm trying some new things in Laravel, how can I redirect the user to a new view ''success page'' after the transaction, instead of having the standard alert of the script?

````
        paypal.Buttons({
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                  value: '0.10' // <---- totale
                }
              }]
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            });
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>  ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that particular callback function you can use `actions.redirect()`

The current PayPal demo now has a sample with that commented as an option, vs. a no-redirect option of showing a message within the `<div>` also: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

---

The general JS answer is to set `window.location.href` to the new destination